# Using WHERE <> in LEFT JOIN criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, where-clause

I am trying to find out if it is possible to use `WHERE <>` on a Left JOIN ON criteria. I hope that makes sense.

Here is the script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      SLA.slxTELEMAGICID,
      sfAccount_Number__c = A.Account_Number__c,
      SLA.slxACCOUNTID,
      sfId = A.Id
      INTO #sfEXACTIVEACCOUNTS
        FROM #slxACTIVEACCOUNTS SLA
              LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT A
                ON SLA.slxTELEMAGICID = A.Account_Number__c
                WHERE SLA.slxTELEMAGICID is NULL OR SLA.slxTELEMAGICID ='N' OR SLA.slxTELEMAGICID <> A.Account_Number__c
                ORDER BY SLA.slxTELEMAGICID, A.Account_Number__c
```

The problem with the above script is that it doesn't seem to pull the list of the records whereby `SLA.slxTELEMAGICID <> A.Account_Number__c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish can you elaborate?

Your left join is stating join them on the `slxTELEMAGICID` and `account_number__c`, but in your where clause you're stating you can also retrieve records where the two that were joined in the join clause do not match - except this condition would not be met as they would have already been filtered by the join.

Your join criteria themselves can have multiple conditions in the join, like such:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      SLA.slxTELEMAGICID,
      sfAccount_Number__c = A.Account_Number__c,
      SLA.slxACCOUNTID,
      sfId = A.Id
  INTO #sfEXACTIVEACCOUNTS
  FROM #slxACTIVEACCOUNTS SLA
  LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT A ON SLA.slxTELEMAGICID = A.Account_Number__c
       OR SLA.slxTELEMAGICID is NULL 
       OR SLA.slxTELEMAGICID ='N' 
       OR SLA.slxTELEMAGICID <> A.Account_Number__c
  ORDER BY SLA.slxTELEMAGICID, A.Account_Number__c
```

Though this really seems like it would return all rows wouldn't it?  If you're joining where `slxTELEMAGICID = account_number__c` AND when they're not equal, then that's everything yeah? (save maybe nulls)